# Lovász conjecture and 2-connected graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

A graph is [vertex-transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph) if its automorphism group acts transitively upon its vertices.
A [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) is a path that visits each vertex exactly once.

[Lovász conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_conjecture): Every finite connected vertex-transitive graph contains a Hamiltonian path.
This conjecture is open since almost 50 years.

A [connected graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) is [$2$-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph) if it remains connected  whenever any vertex is removed.
**Question**: Is Lovász conjecture known in the $2$-connected case (or $k$-connected for $k$ large enough)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The vertex connectivity of a vertex-transitive graph with valency $k$ is at least $2(k+1)/3$ (Mader/Watkins). So if you prove the conjecture for 3-connected graphs, you've done them all.

Comment: Theorem 3 in https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021980070800059/1-s2.0-S0021980070800059-main.pdf?_tid=c183a794-8d5f-4c0d-ae0d-6697e08e9dc1&acdnat=1520725957_838afe7bd8517c9f6ff0ed3231f625b5